# How add funtion boots?

Tags: c++

There i need you help.

Error copilation VS14  Add new library boost_1_71_0

persists problem build copilation.

Line Error
readTimer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(Connection::read_timeout));

After build error.
Error   C2440   ''cannot be converted from''.to
'boost::posix_time::seconds'

Comment: Please consider including the actual error as well as the code.  But kudos in making the effort in putting the error as text.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide more info. Try for [ask] and [mre]. Use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help Taking the [tour] is highly recommended.

Comment: What kind of object is `Connection::read_timeout`? What is it's type? Please post here...

Comment: Can you also copy/paste your compilation messages? You seem to be making some spelling errors while retyping the messages.